# Cordova plugin Error within xCode 7 - inAppBrowser / Network Information / Facebook

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cordova, inappbrowser

When I build iOs App in terminal, I get this errors:

**InAppBrowser plugin**

CDVInAppBrowser.m:732:19: warning: null passed to a callee
      that requires a non-null argument [-Wnonnull]

**NetWork InFormation**

CDVConnection.m:121:10: warning: address of
      'UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification' will always evaluate to 'true' [-Wpointer-bool-conversion]

**Facebook Connect Plugin**

FacebookConnectPlugin.m:415:35: warning: null passed to a callee
      that requires a non-null argument [-Wnonnull]

Can somebody fix it? I have a week trying to solve but i can't!

Comment: those are warnings, not errors. Try using the latest version of each plugin

Comment: I'm using the latest version plugins :( Latest Cordova, latest xCode... The error persist!